# How to convert timestamp from GMT to Unix epoch

Tags: java, scala, timestamp, epoch

I'm parsing a timestamp which is **"2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000"**, this format is **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'ZZZZ"** (ISO8601).

I want to convert it in epoch unix time, I'm using java.text.SimpleDateFormat.
I tried two methods but both don't work:

1-  First Method

```
val parsed = "2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000"
val df: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'ZZZZ'")
val date = df.parse(parsed.toString)
val epoch = date.getTime
```

Error showed:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000"
```

2- This second Method shows an output but is incorrect

```
val parsed = "2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000"
val df: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'+0000'")
val date = df.parse(parsed.toString)
val epoch = date.getTime
println(epoch)
```

Output:

```
1642004766492
```

If you convert this epoch to HUMAN DATE: **"Wednesday, 12 January 2022 16:26:06.492"**

The hours,minutes and seconds are wrong.

Comment: Use `java.time` API, `java.text` is outdated.

Comment: Your first method declares `'ZZZZ'` which means the `ZZZZ` string literally. You would want to remove the simple quotes.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer by Alin Gabriel Arhip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is outdated, as Gael pointed out.

The Time API now supports up to nanoseconds, so microseconds are not an issue here. You should use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with `ZonedDateTime`.  Your pattern is slightly wrong. Checking the docs for `Offset Z`:

> Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
> letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute,
> without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the
> offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized
> offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the
> corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. Five
> letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero,
> with colon. It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more letters
> throws IllegalArgumentException.

You can also print the time using `toInstant` to make sure it was parsed correctly:

```
  import java.time.ZonedDateTime
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

  val parsed = "2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000"
  val p = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZ"
  val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p)
  val zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(parsed, dtf)
  println(zdt.toInstant) // 2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492Z
  println(zdt.toInstant.toEpochMilli) // 1642004254512
```

Here is a [nice article](https://mincong.io/2017/02/16/convert-date-to-string-in-java/) that explains in detail converting an ISO 8601 in Java. The comments at the end are particularly useful, as it shows the difference between the different patterns used.

Answer (score 0):

looks like epoch has data in internal datetime format.
and you should convert it to string format
like this in java

```
    public static String dateToString(Date d, String string_format) {
        String result = "";
        if(d != null) {
            result = new SimpleDateFormat(string_format).format(d);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp you have has microseconds precision. Such precision is not supported by `SimpleDateFormat`. Also, Unix epoch time is usually up to milliseconds precision.

Possible solution here is to explicitly round the microseconds to milliseconds in the string **before** parsing, then use the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format.

```
String parsed = "2022-01-12T17:17:34.512492+0000";

String upToSeconds = parsed.substring(0, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss".length());
String microseconds = parsed.substring("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.".length(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.".length() + "SSSSSS".length());
String timezone = parsed.substring("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSS".length());

String roundedMilliseconds = new BigDecimal(microseconds).divide(new BigDecimal("1000"), 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();

String reformatted = upToSeconds + "." + roundedMilliseconds + timezone;
System.out.println(reformatted); // 2022-01-12T17:17:34.512+0000

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
long epoch = sdf.parse(reformatted).getTime();

System.out.println(epoch); // 1642007854512
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch)); // 2022-01-12T17:17:34.512Z
```